# white-space: nowrap doesn't work in element UL

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying don't wrap the letters in multiple lines. I'm using bootstrap too.

My problem:

[image: My example]

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="tabulation">
        <nav class="text-center">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>      
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

CSS by Booststrap:

```
nav {
    display: block;
}
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination>li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I would like to leave all the letters on the same line with scrolling, something like this table. If is too long add the scroll.

[image: Table Example]

See in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLa4wx1h/2/) the example/problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the use of float with `a` (set by default within Bootstrap). Make them `inline-block` instead:

```css
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-size: 0; /*Remove white space*/
  width: 100%;
}

ul.pagination li {
  font-size: initial;
}

ul.pagination li a {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div id="tabulation">
    <nav class="text-center">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">J</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">K</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">N</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">O</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">U</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">V</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, only add `width: 100%;` to `<ul>` to be perfect!

Answer (score 2):

There is the alternative of the [CSS flex layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) which can be enforced on the sample page by replacing the own CSS with the following:

```
.pagination {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
ul, .pagination {
    display:        flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap:      nowrap;
    overflow-x:     auto;
}
li {
    flex:   1 1 auto;
}
```

See it live at [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/xg9y5cur/1/).